# Persistent error "BTRFS error (device sda1): incorrect extent count for 153567100928; counted 221, expected 222" which cannot be fixed

Tags: btrfs

When I open the system log in Ubuntu 20.04 I consistently run in this error:

```
BTRFS error (device sda1): incorrect extent count for 153567100928; counted 221, expected 222
```

I can't get extra information, run further diagnose or fix it through any btrfs tools (btrfs check, ftrim, defrag et al.) How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I end up nuked the partition

Comment: That what I thought I would have to do. Sigh.